# Eclipse Java Version Incorrectly Set Somewhere

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I do not believe this is a duplicate of any of the previous questions concerning Java in Eclipse.

yesterday my machine updated its java version, and after it did that I opened my Eclipse IDE and found I couldn't build most of my Java projects. The last time I used eclipse everything worked and I had not changed any settings.

I should be using java 1.7_80 (my work projects require this), but now when I build my projects eclipse says it is looking for java 1.8_71- but then eclipse says its using java 1.8_77; all the while my Java compiler settings still says I'm using java 1.7...

The Question: Are there any other places in Eclipse where it sets what version of Java is used?

Note: Java 1.7_80 is still in my PATH System Environment variable; those other newer versions are not and never were. I am using ANT. Below are some images to show my problems and settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have images to show my settings but I am having trouble posting them, it believes I am posting code for some reason. They should be up in moments.

Comment: The launch/run configuration also allows to manually set a Java runtime, which overrides the project settings. Therefore check the "Run " and "External Tools" of the used run configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Window->Preferences->Installed JREs`, there eclipse uses the checked JRE to compile and run your product per default.

There is also a "Java Runtime Environment" option in your Run configuration.

You can also specify project specific `Java Compiler` options, rightclick `Properties` on your project.

Edit: for ant launches, see printscreen below:

[image]

Edit2: ok I think for Ant, compiler options are irelevant.
What you can try is storing your ant launch in your project and open it with a text editor and search for invalid java configurations:

- open your ant launch
- goto `Common`
- change to `Shared file`
- choose your project

Comment: I've checked there. The only one I have is 1.7_80. I have images, but I'm having trouble attaching them to my posted question.

Comment: It was the ANT build giving me the java 1.8_71 issue. I accepted this answer since it got the last piece of my issue; despite the other answer also being helpful and solving another part of my issue. That said... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the project and select "**Build Path**" and "**Configure build path**". Then select the library and change the library to the desired one. Also to check which version of java is install you can use "**java -version**" in terminal/ command prompt.

Comment: Thanks, I d removed the update that java did from my computer entirely. (thanks to your advice to jog my memory!) I'm still stuck with eclipse telling me it can't build because its looking for java 1.8_71. I added an image of my build path displaying it is correctly set. Any additional ideas?

Comment: You can add alternate JRE as an environment. To do that double click on the jre system library and put link to the alternate JRE. I think it should work.